# QInputDialog displays a comma instead of a dot for getDouble()

Tags: c++, qt

I use for input of decimal number in Qt `QInputDialog::getDouble()`. For some reason by default outputs instead of a point a comma though in tutorials shows a point.

Can you tell me what it is or can the new versions only use a comma? The dot refuses keyboard

```
double test = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, "Error!", "Write from 0 to 1!", 0.0, -2147483647, 2147483647, 3, &ok );
```

[image]

Comment: Is probably related to your locale settings, as the decimal separator (dot or comma) is language dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the `QLocale` settings of your current system. If you use an instance of `QInputDialog` rather than the static method, you can set the `QLocale` setting yourself (without changing the value for the whole application).

For example:

```
QInputDialog* dialog = new QInputDialog();
dialog->setInputMode(QInputDialog::DoubleInput);
dialog->setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedKingdom)); // Will use a dot
dialog->exec();
qDebug() << dialog->doubleValue();

dialog->setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::French, QLocale::France)); // Will use a comma
dialog->exec();
qDebug() << dialog->doubleValue();
```

See the Qt [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html) to configure the `QInputDialog` (the range, title, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with PyQt. Haven't been able to specify setLocale. So I had to define it from a QInputDialog()

```
    #value, okPressed = QInputDialog.getDouble(self, "Get scale value","Value:", self.scaleValue, 0, 100, 1)
    # --> get comma instead of dot
    dialog = QInputDialog()
    dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.DoubleInput)
    dialog.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.English, QLocale.UnitedStates))
    dialog.setLabelText("Value : ")
    dialog.setDoubleMinimum(0)
    dialog.setDoubleMaximum(100)
    dialog.setDoubleStep(1)
    dialog.setDoubleDecimals(2)
    dialog.setDoubleValue(self.scaleValue)
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Get scale value")
    okPressed = dialog.exec_()
    if okPressed:
        self.scaleValue = dialog.doubleValue()
    else:
        return
```